# onion sites not working

Tags: onion-routing

I am rather new to Tor and not sure if it is something I missed, or that I have done wrong. Almost every single onion site (90% of them) I try to access shows the error message "Unable to connect".

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% normal. Most onion services are run on personal computers and not on enterprise servers and are likely to go down as often as people turn off their computers.

In an [interview](https://archive.fosdem.org/2019/interviews/roger-dingledine/) earlier this year, Roger Dingledine, one of the founders of Tor said:

> "commercial companies like to inflate the size of the “dark web”,
>   which is easy to do when they don’t define what they’re talking about.
>   The reality is that **there are only a few thousand websites available
>   as Tor onion services currently**, which makes the “iceberg” metaphor
>   about the huge dark unknown particularly misleading."

Comment: thanks for clearing that up,i've been trying them all day

Comment: Well that’s right.